# Is there a way to lock a process to a CPU?

Tags: c, linux, api

I am thinking about developing an application that will, on a six core machine, run six asynchronous tasks, one on each core.

But is it possible to lock the tasks to their own core?

The idea is for them to run mostly by themselves, but to sometimes communicate over a shared memory area. However, I want the tasks to run as undisturbed as possible.

Comment: Are you really sure you'll do a better job than the scheduler of deciding which cpu each task should run on? :-)

Comment: @R.., no not sure, but I have a pretty good hunch. The reason is that there are exactly 6 things to do, and they should run as uninterrupted as possible, asynchronously.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is called "thread affinity". How it's implemented and the interfaces to ask for it are OS-specific.

Under Linux, try [sched_setaffinity()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity). glibc may also offer pthread_attr_setaffinity_np().

Answer (score 5):

```
taskset -c cpunum yourprocess
```

does what you want.
It is possible to supply PIDs instead, this way you can set single threads to a cpu. If you want to change the cpu affinity from your own program, use `sched_setaffinity()`.

Answer (score 4):

Not lock, but it is possible to associate a [cpu affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) for a process

Answer (score 1):

Just for the records, another method, not involving programming:
Open Task Manager, go to Processes tab, right click your process and choose Set Affinity...

Comment: the question is tagged Linux - you can't assume there's even a mouse connected, let alone a complete gui with a "task manager"

Comment: @Mat You are perfectly right. Anyway, this might help others.